# Starting a class from a separate class

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a TCP server/client system. Currently I've created a `ConnectionFrame.java` file, including a `JFrame` with a `JButton`, `JTextArea` and a `JTextField`. When starting my client, I want this `JFrame` to appear (therefore when I start my client.jar, the `ConnectionFrame` should be executed as well.

I assumed I could do this by putting following line into the clients main method:

```
ConnectionFrame cf = new ConnectionFrame();
```

But with no luck. Another try was writing:

```
ConnectionFrame.main(argv);
```

Which for some reason seemed to mess up my original code.

EDIT: Adding code for context

The ConnectionFrame:

```
public class ConnectionFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton buttonLayout = new JButton("Connect to server");
    JTextField textFieldLayout = new JTextField(1);
    JTextArea consoleOutput = new JTextArea(1,20);

    public void addComponentToPane(Container pane) {

        buttonLayout.addActionListener(this);
        textFieldLayout.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        consoleOutput.setEditable(false);

        pane.add(buttonLayout, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        pane.add(textFieldLayout, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(consoleOutput, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); 
    }

    public static void ConnectionFrame() {
        ConnectionFrame frame = new ConnectionFrame();
        frame.addComponentToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if("Connect to server".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
            consoleOutput.append("CONSOLE: Triggered");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionFrame();
    }
}
```

The Client:

```
public class TCPClient {

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        ConnectionFrame cf = new ConnectionFrame();

        String sentence;
        String modifiedSentence;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 54343);
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        CanvasFrame myFrame = new CanvasFrame();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        ArrayList<Point> points = myFrame.location;

        outToServer.writeInt(points.size());

        for(Point p : points)
        {
            outToServer.writeInt(p.x);
            outToServer.writeInt(p.y);
        }

        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to schedule the creation task for the `event-dispatching thread` like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ConnectionFrame();
            }
        }
);
```

In java 8 it will be:

```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ConnectionFrame::ConnectionFrame);
```